# Selenium - Fetching Information Whose Associated Web Element's Tag Keeps Changing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Given a search term, I'm trying to fetch the results that come up on Amazon under the category *Books* and get the details of each book for the given search term.

I'm running into an issue where sometimes my code is able to find the results and other times it fails. After checking this further, I realized the items are sometimes listed with `<li>` tags and at other times with `<div>` tags.

Pasted below is the element and code snippets for the same element to backup my claim.

[image]

HTML with `<li>` tag:

```
<li id="result_0" data-asin="0128023074" class="s-result-item celwidget  ">
```

HTML with `<div>` tag:

```
<div data-asin="0128023074" data-index="0" class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28" data-cel-widget="search_result_0"><div class="sg-col-inner">
```

I'm still a newbie to Selenium and so to get over this problem, I'm using the following snippet of code and I'm pretty sure there's a better way to handle this.

```
try:
    book = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "result_0")))
    book_detail(book, details)
except TimeoutException:
    book = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-index=\"0\" and @data-cel-widget=\"search_result_0\"]")))
    book_detail_by_div(book, details)
```

Can someone please help me understand why the tag associated changes like this and also how to handle a situation like this ?

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I've edited my question to include the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question of why this happened, I am not sure. I tried different OS/Browser and window sizes, but could not reproduce case of `div` elements.

To improve your code I have a suggestion, but it may not be the best solution for you, so you can try. This will wait for any of the two types of elements to be visible together, instead of waiting 10 seconds for first type and then second.

```
try:
    book = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[(@id="result_0") or (@data-index="0" and @data-cel-widget="search_result_0")]')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Did not find search result")
else:
    # So atleast one of the tag type is visible.
    # Even if the attribute is not present then it will return None.
    if book.get_attribute('id') == "result_0":
        book_detail(book, details)
    else:
        book_detail_by_div(book, details)
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the details provided within the question and on `https://www.amazon.com` searching for the text **The Data and Analytics playbook** the same element was displayed.

So, your observation with the `<div>` tag was correct. However I didn't find any relevant `<li>` tag near around the search results.

### Solution

To identify the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility of element located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  book = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sg-col-inner h5 a:first-child")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  book = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sg-col-inner']//h5//following::a[1]/span")))
  ```